# My code will run and then when it reaches a certain function I have TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, typeerror

Meaning line  **slow_cost= slow_len * A     fast_cost = fast_len * R** in my function ave_chop_time. Where did I go wrong?

It is running fine and I guess my function ave_chop_time has no value to it. Also, before it didn't say L was undefined and now it is.

```
 import random

slice_list= [0,100]
size_limit= L
#L is defined by user input as seen below

def get_piece_sizes(slice_list):
    piece_sizes=[]
    for i in range(len(slice_list)-1):
        piece_sizes.append(slice_list[i+1]-slice_list[i])
    return piece_sizes

def fast_slices(size_limit, slice_list):
    done= False
    while (not done):
        cut= round(random.uniform(0,100),5)
        slice_list.append(cut)
        slice_list.sort()
        
        p**strong text**iece_sizes=get_piece_sizes(slice_list)
        if max(piece_sizes)<=size_limit:
            return slice_list
        
def slow_slices(size_limit, slice_list):
    i=0
    for i in range(len(slice_list)):
        slow_slice_diff= [slice_list[-1] - slice_list[-2]]
        # checking if the slice_list is smaller than the size_limit
        #from subrtacting from the second to last element 
        if max(slow_slice_diff) == size_limit:
            return slice_list
        elif max(slow_slice_diff) > size_limit:
            x=slice_list[-2] + size_limit
            slice_list. append(x)
            slice_list.sort()
            return slow_slices(size_limit, slice_list)
        
def ave_chop_time(slice_list,fast_limit,slow_limit,fast_cost, slow_cost,n):
    total_cost=0
    for i in range(n):
        fast_sliced= fast_slices(fast_limit, slice_list)
        slow_sliced= slow_slices(slow_limit, slice_list)
        fast_len=len(fast_sliced) 
        slow_len=len(slow_sliced)
        slow_cost= slow_len * A
        fast_cost = fast_len * R
        total_cost= slow_cost + fast_cost
        return total_cost/n      
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Welcome to my average chop time calculator!")
L = float(input("Give the overall size limit: "))
R = float(input("Give the time cost for a random slice: "))
A = float(input("Give the time cost for an accurate slice: "))
print("The average chopping times by random slice size limit: ")
print("{:18} {:18}".format("fast_limit", "ave_chop_time"))
for i in range(0, int(101 - L), 5):
    print("{:<18f} {:<18f}".format(L+i, ave_chop_time([0,100], L+i, L, R, A, 100)))
```

Comment: Your `return total_cost/n` shouldn't be indented like that; the for loop will only run once, since it returns during the loop.

Have you ensured slow_sliced is not `None`? If max(slow_slice_diff) < size_limit, then it doesn't return anything in particular. Also, not sure what the `max` is there for...

Comment: without the max I get TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'. When I tested the function I was getting output therefore something is wrong with the ave_chop_time function

Comment: Oh, I misread and didn't notice it was a list, sorry.

Comment: no worries, however Im still experiencing the same problem after i fixed the indent any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of what @Putnam said, in testing everything will work out fine (as far as I know) if you replace:

```
if max(slow_slice_diff) == size_limit:
            return slice_list
```

With:

```
if max(slow_slice_diff) <= size_limit:
            return slice_list
```